# Could not find a declaration file for module '@hmscore/react-native-hms-push'

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I'm having problems with linking push kit library.

I'm programming in react-native with visual studio  code, library '@hmscore/react-native-hms-push' not seem to be imported correctly, the error is 'Could not find a declaration file for module '@hmscore/react-native-hms-push'.

I'm using 5.3.0-301 version.

Checking maps-kit and push-kit seems different si index.ts, is missing in the src directory of push-kit

i have used this guide:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/integraternmodule-0000001050157791

have i missed anything?

Thanks

Comment: hi@Luca Parlapiano, to solve this issue, may i ask are you using NPM or changing it locally? Seems there may be something wrong with [this Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29ryI.png).

Comment: i have checked all steps, is all o.k. Only difference is that I used yarn instead of npm. I don't understand, the steps are the same of maps plugin ... but maps works fine, push kit no.. is strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
yarn add @types/hmscore__react-native-hms-push
```

or equivalent in **npm**.